# Get the creation date of an Azure IotHub device / twin

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I would like to be able to sort the devices registered on a given Azure IoTHub by creation date.

I tried fetching this devices list through  several tools:

- using the official CLI with `az iot hub device-identity list …`, inspecting the JSON formatted output of this command
- using the Node.js Azure SDK

The returned objects have various fields dealing with dates :

- `lastActivityTime`
- `statusUpdateTime`

But none of them are initialized to the creation date.

To circumvent this apparent lack of data, I currently have to listen to Azure EventGrid `DeviceCreated` events and manually set arbitrary `createdAt` field on the targeted digital-twin tags.

This solution is quite cumbersome, I feel like I'm missing something more obvious.

Is there any simpler way to get the creation date of an Azure IotHub device / twin?

Comment: Can you have your device code set the created date in a device twin property when the device connects for the for the first time?

Answer (score -1):

We can retrieve the date and time of the IoT hub creation using both from the portal as well using the JSON file created after the creation of IoT hub and using the code part with subscription ID under the specific resource, we are getting the information of the date and time of the IoT hub. Follow the below procedure to retrieve the information.

[image]

Created the iot-hub instance

The date and time of creation is available on the screen

[image]

Using the JSON file we can see the date and time of creation.

[image]

Copy the JSON request and follow the steps mentioned in the [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-hub/iot-hub-python-python-device-management-get-started.md) mentioned and retrieve the data. The same procedure for both digital twins and individual entities.

Comment: He asked about the device creation date, not the hub.